# Switch the values from x-axis to y-axis while using the correct labels(Python Matplotlib.pyplot OR Seaborn)

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, histogram, axis

I have a small table of information that I'm trying to turn into a histogram. It has one column of Department names and a second column of totals. I would like the x-axis to use the Department names and the y-axis to use the numbers from the totals column. When I try to code it, the x-axis is the totals and the y-axis is a count of how many of those totals fit into the bins.

Title: deptgroups (my dataframe)

| department | count |
| --- | --- |
| Admin | 857 |
| Engineering | 26 |
| IT | 49 |
| Marketing | 16 |
| Operations | 1013 |
| Sales | 1551 |

Data as "datagroups.csv"

```
department,count,
Admin,857,
Engineering,26,
IT,49,
Marketing,16,
Operations,1013,
Sales,1551
```

```
plt.hist(x=deptgroups)
plt.show()
```

[Incorrect Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XPOMd.png)

I've tried specifying x and y values, but it throws an error. I would like it to look more like this (ish):

| Qty | Dept 1 | Dept 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 500 | XXXXXX | ...... |
| 400 | XXXXXX | ...... |
| 300 | XXXXXX | XXXXXX |
| 200 | XXXXXX | XXXXXX |
| 100 | XXXXXX | XXXXXX |

The original data for example would look like this:
|Department | Count|
|-----------|------|
|Dept 1     | 500  |
|Dept 2     | 300  |

Comment: Please provide full code including hardcoded data so people can modify it

Comment: I hope I was able to fix it to make more sense. I'll see what I can do about figuring out how to include the hardcoded data.

Comment: You have python code that generated incorrect plot, publish it. Something like `deptgroups={'Admin': 857, 'Engineering': 26}`

Comment: I think I've got it in csv format? Thank you for your patience! I'm super new. :)

Comment: OK, but your question is not about reading a CSV file. See how I define data in my answer, this is something you can run immediately. Please consult [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think main confusion is coming from the name of the plot. It's called bar chart, histogram is something else.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = {
    'Admin': 857,
    'Engineering': 26,
    'IT': 49,
    'Marketing': 16,
    'Operations': 1013,
    'Sales': 1551
}
departments = data.keys()
count = data.values()

# you don't need histogram, you need bar plot
plt.bar(departments, count, color='blue', width=0.4)
plt.xlabel('Department')
plt.ylabel('Count')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Oh  my gosh! Thank you so much! I was positive it should have been a histogram because it was numbers in categories, but I see where I was incorrect.